# Add a single row containing text taking up entire area of WPF Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a WPF datagrid and I would like to display a message saying "No Records Found" in the middle of the Datagrid.

One way I can see of doing this is to add a single datarow that spans all the columns and whos height is the height of the datagrid, then centre the text in the row.

The main thing Im struggling with is programatically adding the row to teh datagrid.

Is this possible or is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the 'No Records Found' message in a `TextBlock` instead, and show/hide the `TextBlock` depending on whether the `DataGrid` has data.

```
<Grid>

  <DataGrid x:Name="_dataGrid" />

  <TextBlock 
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    Visibility="{Binding ElementName=_dataGrid, Path=HasItems, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToInverseVisibilityConverter}, Mode=OneWay}">
      No Records Found
  </TextBlock>

</Grid>
```

EDIT: Source for `BooleanToInverseVisibilityConverter` (I have a bunch of handy converters like this always available to me in my WPF projects)

```
public class BooleanToInverseVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter {

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        return (bool) value ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes. Both the DataGrid and the TextBlock are in a Grid, and the TextBlock HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment are both Center, so that the TextBlock will show in the centre, overlaid on top of the DataGrid.

Answer (score 1):

You can add items to the datagrid programatically like this:

```
myDataGrid.Items.Add(new MyDataGridItem());
```

If you have set the ItemsSource of the datagrid to some collection or something, you need to modify that collection instead. You can do that like this:

```
myCollection.Add(new MyDataGridItem());
myDataGrid.ItemsSource = null;
myDataGrid.ItemsSource = myCollection;
```